# A data structure that supports finding the max number between 2 indexes in O(1)

Tags: data-structures

I've been asked the following question:

Given an array of `n` different numbers, devise a data structure that supports finding the max number in an interval (that is given by 2 indexes - high and low bound) with O(1) time complexity.

So for example if the indexes given are `i,j` (such that i < j), find the `Max(A[i],A[i+1],…,A[j])` in O(1) time complexity. (in other words given `i,j` I need to figure out which of the following is the largest number: A[i],A[i+1],…,A[j])
Initializing time allowed for the data structure is O(n^2). No other limitations.

I came up with a few ideas, but I couldn't think of something that is straight forward, and can be proved to meet the requirements.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Think of how selection sort works. You could use a very similar algorithm to build your data structure. That's an O(n^2) algorithm. The resulting data structure would contain `(n^2 - n)/2` entries.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the hint. I came up with a few ideas, and one of them was something that might be similar to what you are suggesting, in my opinion.
However it turned out that i need to use selection sort n times, which results in O(n^3) time.
So perhaps I didn't get it right, could you give me just another hint or advice? 
Thanks

Comment: How about posting your code, or pseudo code, showing us your O(n^3) solution? Then we can help you understand how to improve it.

Comment: The obvious choice would be a 2D array containing the answer for every i,j pair...

Comment: A segment tree can do that with O(n log n) storage, O(n log n) build-up time, and O(log n) query, using way less memory and a bit more time.

Comment: @Taegyung That's a nice idea!

Comment: This is a famous computer science problem called ["range minimum query"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_minimum_query). It can be solved in linear initialization time and O(1) query time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The brute force way to solve this is to build an nxn array, and fill that array with the answer for each `[i,j]`. The general idea is:

```
a[] // this is the input array
results = new [n,n]

// this is the same loop structure used for selection sort
for (i = 0; i < n-1; ++i)
{
    largest = a[i]
    results[i,i] = largest
    for (j = i+1; j < n; ++j)
    {
        if (a[j] > largest)
        {
            largest = a[j]
        }
        results[i,j] = largest
     }
}
```

Given the array `[1, 2, 5, 3, 4]`, that should create:

```
1, 2, 5, 5, 5
?, 2, 5, 5, 5
?, ?, 5, 5, 5
?, ?, ?, 3, 4
?, ?, ?, ?, 4
```

The question marks signify that we don't care what the values are there. If you're queried with values i and j, you just look up `results[i,j]`, and you have your answer. Because `i < j`, you'll never index any of the cells that have question marks.

So the init time is O(n^2), and the space required is O(n^2).

Comment: That settles it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this would work? You remember the largest and smallest numbers as they are added to the array, so when you are queried for the answer for the max range, you already know it (ie O(1))

```
class SmartArray{
   innerArray=[];
   smallest;
   largest;

   //There are edge cases here when the array is 
   //0 or 1 elements that you might have to work out
   add(element){
      innerArray.add(element);
      if(element>largest){
         largest=element
      }
      if(element<smallest){
         smallest=element
      }
   }

   //Definitely O(1)
   getMaxNumber(){
      return largest-smallest;
   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.
Sorry, I think I didn't present the question clearly enough.
Given i,j I need to figure out which of the following is the highest: A[i],A[i+1],…,A[j]
And not the maximum range.